# How does one use ML inequality with this equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I use the ML - Inequality to prove that

$$\lvert \oint_Cf(z) \,dz \rvert \le \frac{2\pi R}{R^2 -1}$$

where C is the upper half-circle and $\lvert z \rvert = R$, and $ 0 \le Im  \, z$

where $$f(z) = \frac{1+ e^{2iz}}{z^2 +1} $$

What I have done so far:

$ L = \pi R $, because it is a upper half circle

Finding M is more cumbersome, so what I have tried so far is to use the triangle inequality

$$ \lvert \frac{1+ e^{2iz}}{z^2 +1} \rvert \lt \lvert \frac{1+ e^{2iz}}{z^2 -1} \rvert   $$

And the right hand side can be written as:

$$\lvert \frac{1+ e^{2iz}}{R^2 -1} \rvert  $$

but I am unsure how to proceed from here, I understand that  $  1 + e^{2iz}$ should be equal to $2$. Which means that $e^{2iz}$ shold equal $1$.

What I tried was to express $z$ as $x+iy$, but I could not find a way to proceed from there. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|1+e^{2iz}|\le1+|e^{2iz}|=2$.
So, we have 
$$\lvert \frac{1+ e^{2iz}}{R^2 -1} \rvert \le \frac{2}{R^2-1} $$
Now, 
$$\lvert \oint_Cf(z) \,dz \rvert \le \oint_C\frac{2}{R^2-1} dz \;,$$ where $C$ is semi-circle. So, $$\lvert \oint_Cf(z) \,dz \rvert \le \frac{2}{R^2-1}\oint_Cdz \;\le \frac{2\pi R}{R^2-1}$$

The statement 'I understand that you should $1+e^{2iz}$ should be equal to $2$. Which means that e$^{2iz}$ should equal $1$' is not the correct statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where do you get $|1+e^{2iz}|\le1+|e^{2iz}|=2$ from? How do you prove this?

Comment: @dondeman $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$ (triangle inequality) and clearly,$|e^{2iz}|=1, \;\forall\; z$ .